# How to config iPage php ini to work with laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, laravel, web-hosting

I recently registered to iPage web hosting, they are providing PHP Version 5.3.13 but Laravel 4.2 required **PHP Version >= 5.4**

Please guide me, how can I upgrade iPage php version or how can I configure laravel 4.2 to run?

Comment: Get a better host. Their docs say they don't currently support PHP 5.4, which makes them dangerously irresponsible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the specific features/capabilities of an individual webhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  Shared hosts like iPage (shared meaning they're based on traditional unix multiuser systems) do not allow end users to upgrade the version of PHP running on a server -- doing so would be chaos, as all users share the same PHP binaries.

Some shared hosts install multiple versions of PHP on their servers and provide a mechanism that allows users to switch between versions.  It [looks like iPage might offer this feature](http://www.ipage.com/knowledgebase/beta/article.bml?ArticleID=2124), although it's unclear if PHP 5.4 will be an option.